# keyboard - resizing viewgroup, overlaying viewgroups and custom editor view

Tags: java, android

im writing a keyboard and there are a number of things i want to do:

1) i want to be able to dyamically resize the the keyboard view. I
have a custom view for my keyboard, created by my
InputMethodService.onCreateInputView

i've tried calling invalidate, requestLayout, forceLayout, on the
keyboard view, on its parent and on the view root but nothing seems to
call the onMeasure code again in my layout to allow it to resize.

2) i would also like to have a view group that goes over the edit
window and possibly over the rest of the screen. for example if the
user preses a button i want to draw above thier finger (which could be
over the editor window) what the are pressing or some additional
information.

3) i would like to be able to disable the editor window and do this my
self, so for example i can change how this functions